# How can i access image url from list of images

Tags: flutter

I am having a model which holds product details. i am getting all the product details and outputting them successfully except for the List of images. The product model consist of list of images, so i don't know how to map the individual images.

Product Model

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Product {
  @JsonKey(name: '_id')
  String? id;
  int? quantity;
  String? description;
  int? offer;
  final List<ProductImages>? productPictures;
  String? reviews;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.quantity,
    this.description,
    this.offer,
    this.productPictures,
    this.reviews,
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['productPictures'] as List;
    // print(list.runtimeType);
    List<ProductImages> imagesList =
        list.map((i) => ProductImages.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Product(
        id: json['_id'] as String?,
        quantity: json['quantity'] as int?,
        description: json['description'] as String?,
        offer: json['offer'] as int?,
        productPictures: imagesList);
  }
}
```

Produt Controller

```
 void fetchAllProducts() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var response = await networkHandler.get(ApiUtil.fetchAllProduct);
      productSuper.value = ProductSuper.fromJson(response);
      data = productSuper.value.data!;
    } catch (ex) {
      print({ex, 'An error occured, cannot fetch products'});
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

View

```
      I am getting the product details successfully, example is the product quantity below, 
so how can i access the productPictures since it is a list.



  Text(
      product.quantity!,
      style: TextStyle(
      color: AppColors.primaryText,
      fontSize: 14.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
       ),
     ),


    child: MyCachedNetworkImage(
           imageurl: product.productPictures.map  // how can i access the product pictures from the list,
           ),
```

Comment: Could you show what the `ProductImages` class looks like?

Comment: also how do you want to show the images? like a row? column? listview?

Comment: To show the first one, you'd do something like: `product.productPictures[0].url` (assuming that there will always be at least one - otherwise you could show a place holder). As @h8moss alludes to, if there's more than one, you'll have to put them in a row or column - or get some sort of carousel.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  This solved my issues - product.productPictures[0].url

Comment: Can you please share your ```ProductImages``` class. It would help me with my app